# Specifying module locations in NPM tsc compiler

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc

**The context**

I have an Angular 2 app that, for organizational purposes, I would like to store across three different repositories, for example one for reusable widgets, another for a working app that only certain users should see, another that other users should see, etc. I don't want these to be minified all together in production, as that will involve delivering to the end user lots of code that isn't pertinent to them. Rather, I want each app to be minified, and only requested by the end working app when needed.

**The problem**

I will obviously need to specify component names rather than absolute paths when I import components in my code. For example:

```
import { MyComponent } from '../../other-repo/app/components/my.component/my.component';
```

will have to be different in production, to refer to the minified file that repo is in. So I would like to be able to use module paths like

```
import { MyComponent } from 'OtherRepo.myComponent';
```

Staying as close as possible to the Heroes tutorial set up, **systemjs.config.js** can be told to look for `myComponent` by setting a property in its `map` property:

```
var map = {
  'app':  'app', // 'dist',
  'OtherRepo.myComponent': '../../other-repo/app/components/my.component',
  ...
}
```

In theory, I could set up a build process using Grunt, Gulp, or something similar, to turn this file into a template which contains different paths depending on whether it's the dev or prod build.

The problem is the NPM `tsc` compiler. This configuration works fine when I'm already running the app and let it reload. But when running the NPM `tsc` compiler when I first begin running the app, it complains that it can't find `myComponent`. I've tried adding things like this to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"paths": {
  "MyComponent": "../../other-repo/app/component/my-component"
}
```

both inside and outside of the `compilerOptions` block, but that doesn't work. I've also tried naming the property `map` instead, but that also doesn't work. Unfortunately, the only way to get this working seems to be to change the `moduleResolution` property to `classic` rather than `node`, but then I won't be able to do things like `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

Is there a way to configure NPM's `tsc` compiler to allow me to specify module locations?

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: 1.8.10, according to what's in `node_modules/typescript/package.json`.

Comment: I think to use multiple repos you need to have several tsconfig.json files. You should look into that : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3645